# Mocha: how to assert a promise rejection?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, mocha.js

I'm trying to get Mocha to display the error and also assert a rejected promise on my Node code - ...instead of showing a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` for an exception which is causing my async function to be rejected.

I've searched and tried many suggestions for dealing with this warning and promise rejections in Mocha, but none of them worked for me. It seems to be a recurrent topic and a very confusing one for many people.

I'm trying to do it by:

- using lambda function
- without using `done`
- using simple asserts (I don't like `expect` and `should`)
- handling errors through try/catch (I don't like chained `.then` and `.catch`; and dislike it even more if using `.then(res,err)`)

Something like:

```
it('should give an error', 
  async ()=> {
    try{
      await generateException()
      assert(true)
    } catch(err) {
      console.err(err)
      assert ??? // how to 'assert' a promise rejection?
    }
  }
)
```

If it's unavoidable to use any of the things I don't like much, fine. But what is the closer solution to what I would like?

Also, I don't get why the rejected promise wouldn't be caught in the try/catch, as I would expect, since this is exactly the point of using `await` (making async code work as if they were synchronous).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This works for me. For example purposes, using chai for assertions.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('test', function () {

  function generateException() {
    throw new Error('test error');
  }


  it('should give an error', async ()=> {
    try {
      await generateException();
      expect(true).to.be.false;
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      expect(err.message).to.equal('test error');
    }
  })
})
```

There seems to be a difference in the way of using `Promise.reject()` vs. `throw new Error()`. When the function `generateException` throws an error, your tests work.
However, if it was `Promise.reject()` it never gets to the catch block.

If you do something like `let result = await generateException();` you will see that it is the error you are expecting if the `geenerateException` function uses promise reject.

You can chain promises with await if you choose to.

```
function generateException() {
  return new Promise(reject => {
   return reject(new Error('Promise Rejected');
})

it('should give an error', async ()=> {
  await generateException().catch(error => {
    expect(error.message).to.equal('Promise Rejected');

  })
});
```

Reading parts of [this article on async code](https://codeburst.io/node-express-async-code-and-error-handling-121b1f0e44ba) might help a bit.

Comment: I guess the part I'm (and many others) struggling with is in understanding "why?!" a Promise.reject()  never gets to the catch block...

Comment: https://medium.com/@yamalight/danger-of-using-async-await-in-es7-8006e3eb7efb might shed some light on that.

Comment: but this article actually says in "Option 1" that the try/catch should capture the error... so, why not it the mocha example too?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to test for promise rejection using the [assert](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertrejectsasyncfn-error-message) library

```
import { strict as assert } from 'assert'
it('should give an error', async function () {
    await assert.rejects(generateException())
})
```

If you need the error printed you could do

```
import { strict as assert } from 'assert'
it('should give an error', async function () {
    await assert.rejects(generateException()).catch((err) => {
        console.err(err)
        throw err
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using mocha** unit testing

assert Node Modules:
this is my suggestion:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const PromiseFail = async (proms) => await assertPromise(proms, false);
const PromiseSucced = async (proms) => await assertPromise(proms);
const assertPromise = async (prom, succed = true) => {
    succed = succed ? true : false;
    try {
        prom = Array.isArray(prom) ? prom : [prom];
        await Promise.all(prom);
        assert.strictEqual(true, succed);
    }
    catch (ex) { assert.notStrictEqual(true, succed, ex); }
}
```

while testing:

```
describe('unit test', () => {
 it('test 1', async () => {
        await PromiseSucced(Promise.resolve(1))
        await PromiseSucced([Promise.resolve(2), Promise.resolve(3)])
        const promise4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(reject, 100, 'foo');
        });
        await PromiseFail(promise4)
    });
})
```